# loading huge XLS data into Oracle using python

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have a 3+ million record XLS file which i need to dump in Oracle 12C DB (direct dump) using a python 2.7.

I am using Cx_Oracle python package to establish connectivity to Oracle , but reading and dumping the XLS (using openpyxl pckg) is extremely slow and performance degrades for thousands/million records.

From a scripting stand point used two ways-

1. I've tried bulk load , by reading all the values in array and then dumping it using cursor prepare (with bind variables) and cursor fetchmany.This doesn't work well with huge data.
2. Iterative loading of the data as it is being fetched.Even this way has performance issues.

What options and techniques/packages can i deploy as a best practise to load this volume of data from XLS to Oracle DB ?Is it advisable to load this volume of data via scripting or should i necessarily use an ETL tool ?
As of now i only have option via python scripting so please do answer the former

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If is possible to export your excel fila as a CSV, then all you need is to use `sqlldr` to load the file in db

Comment: This is the best option. Can you convert your `xls` to a `csv` or is there an issue with the structure that requires you do some preprocessing? Python may feel fast some times, but when you have a massive table it will slow you down. You should lead via oracles `sqlldr` which is optimised for loading and will be far faster.

Comment: i can convert XLS to CSV.Can i call SQL loader from Python as i am looking at a batch file automated solution ?

Comment: you do not need python, sqlldr is an oracle tool for loading data in db, extremely fast. some info about sqlldr: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ . it is better to speak with your dba about how to use  sqlldr

Comment: Yeah, but then that someone has to manually upload the CSV each time via sqlldr.I am looking towards more an automated solution where a cron job runs the script at a given time

Comment: Why manually? You put your sqlldr command in a shell/bat file which can be run as a cron jobs

Comment: sqlldr is a good idea, but realy can python process it better then loader?

Comment: Python's performance is bad to load huge data files .Used sqlldr and made a batch script of it.Python script internally calls that script before proceeding with other transformations , so it worked out.Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Basically for high volume data any language going to be stressed on I/O, **except C**. Best way is to use native tools/utilities provided by the DB vendor.
For oracle the correct fit is SQL Loader.

Refer this link for quick tutorial
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/oracle-sqlldr/

Here you go… Sample code that runs SQL Loader and gets you back with return code, output & error

```
sql_ld_command = ['sqlldr ',  'uid/passwd', 'CONTROL=', 
'your_ctrl_file_path', 'DATA=', 'your_data_file_path']   

sql_ldr_proc  = subprocess.Popen(sql_ld_command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)   

out, err  = sql_ldr_proc.communicate()  
retn_code = sql_ldr_proc.wait()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are all of the steps: load xlsx, produce csv (tab delimited) and ctrl file, load with sqlldr.

```
# %%
import sys
import pandas as pd
import subprocess
# %%
user = 'in_user_name'
password = 'in_password'
host = 'in_host'
database = 'in_service_name'
in_file = r"in_file.xlsx"
in_sheet_name = 'in_sheet'
tablename = 'in_table'

# %%
df = pd.read_excel(in_file, sheet_name=in_sheet_name)
print(f"Loaded {df.shape[0]} records from {in_file}")
# %%
inflie = f'{tablename}.csv'
controlfile = f'{tablename}.ctrl'
# %%,
df.to_csv(inflie, index=False, sep='\t',)
# %%
columns = df.columns.tolist()
with open(controlfile, 'w') as file:
    header = f"""OPTIONS (SKIP=1, DIRECT=TRUE ) 
LOAD DATA
INFILE '{inflie}' 
BADFILE '{tablename}.bad'
DISCARDFILE '{tablename}.dsc'
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE {tablename}
FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'9'  
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( """
    file.write(header)
    for c in columns[:-1]:
        file.write(f'{c},\n')
    file.write(f'{columns[-1]})')
# %%
sqlldr_command = f"""sqlldr USERID='{user}/{password}@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST={host})(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME ={database}) ))'  control={controlfile}"""
print(f"Running sqlldr. Log file: {tablename}.log")
subprocess.call(sqlldr_command, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel also comes with ODBC support so you could pump straight from Excel to Oracle assuming you have the drivers. That said, anything that involves transforming a large amount of data in memory (from whatever Excel is using internally) and then passing it to the DB is likely to be less performant than a specialised bulk operation which can be optimised to use less memory. Going through Python just adds another layer to the task (Excel to Python to Oracle), though it might be possible to set this up to use streams.

Answer (score 0):

Automate the export of XLSX to CSV as mentioned in a previous answer.  But, instead of then calling a sqlldr script, create an external table that uses your sqlldr code.  It will load your table from the CSV each time the table is selected from.