# Load incoming files into database using Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'll be receiving different set of files, say, around 10000 files, in 10 minutes. How can I load the data in the files to the Oracle database using Python?

Answer (score 0):

you haven't mentioned the file format you need to load, anyway you may try to use sqlldr and load the file in db, use python to convert your file into csv format and invoke the sqlldr, do check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/30324469/6039974

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  The file format is Json format.   I would like to process the data using cx_Oracle.   Would like to know more about the mutiprocessing and multithreading in python.  How it can be applicable here to process more faster with performance.

Comment: performance wise you can stick with sqlldr, anyway if you want to know about multiprocessing this [link](http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line/) will give you a head start.